# CSS for multi HTML layer

Tags: html, css

I have 2 or 3 div tags, position of them is absolute, so they are overlap and have the same parent, like this

```
<div class="parent">
   <div class="div1"></div>
   <div class="div2"></div>
   <div class="div3"></div>
</div>
```

I set css for div1 "cursor: not-allowed;", but it not apply because div1 is under div2 and div3.
Is there any way to inherit cursor of under layer ? I want when I move pointer to div1, it show "not-allowed".

Thanks

Comment: Can you make a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) ?

Comment: JSFiddle with your CSS?

Comment: Would a `z-index` not work..?

Comment: This is my case: http://jsfiddle.net/n9L2N/1/, I added css to show cursor not-allowed, but I can't click on a slot

Answer (score 1):

You could use `pointer-events: none` on the 2 divs, but [support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events) is limited for IE. [Here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mm453/).

Comment: I added, but in my case, it seem not good. You can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/n9L2N/1/

Answer (score 1):

You could bump the z-index on div1 to push it above the other two. I'm not sure if that would ruin your design, but if div1 could be displayed "on top" of the other two, it might do the trick.

```
.parent div {
    position: absolute;
}
.div1 {
    z-index: 1;
    cursor: not-allowed;
    background: blue;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
.div2 {
    background: yellow;
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
}
.div3 {
    background: green;
    height: 100px;
    width: 300px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way is to set that cursor on their common .parent div. And use default cursor:auto on children of the .parent.